# Trying to install dynamixel_controllers in Fuerte getting error

Tags: dynamixel, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### I'm attempting to install the dynamixel_controllers package in Fuerte. This is a fresh installation of Fuerte on a 12.04 machine. I'm receiving this error after downloading the package and typing "rosmake dynamixel_controllers" I receive this error:
`[ rosmake ] rosmake starting... [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['dynamixel_controllers'] [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/joe/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130719-115348 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['dynamixel_controllers'] to: ['dynamixel_controllers'] [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ] [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ] [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang [rosmake-2] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ] [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ] [rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ] [rosmake-2] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs  No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs [rosmake-4] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ] [rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ] [rosmake-2] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ] [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy [rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamixel_msgs [ make ] [rosmake-4] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs [rosmake-5] Starting >>> control_msgs [ make ] [rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp [rosmake-3] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ] [rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs [rosmake-4] Starting >>> dynamixel_driver [ make ] [rosmake-2] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs [rosmake-3] Finished <<< actionlib  No Makefile in package actionlib [rosmake-5] Finished <<< control_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package control_msgs No Makefile in package control_msgs [rosmake-4] Finished <<< dynamixel_driver [PASS] [ 0.57 seconds ] [rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamixel_msgs [PASS] [ 1.08 seconds ] [rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamixel_controllers [ make ] [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesnamixel_controllers: 3.6... [ 1 Active 12/13 Complete ] {------------------------------------------------------------------------------- valid_packages = valid_packages + rospack.get_depends(package_context, implicit=True) TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "set") to list make[3]: *** [../srv_gen/lisp/StartController.lisp] Error 1 make[3]: *** [../srv_gen/lisp/SetTorqueLimit.lisp] Error 1 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 873, in <module> generate_srv(sys.argv[1]) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 822, in generate_srv write_srv_component(s, spec.request, spec) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 697, in write_srv_component write_md5sum(s, spec, parent) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 596, in write_md5sum compute_files=False) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 314, in get_dependencies _add_msgs_depends(rospack, spec.response, deps, package) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 75, in _add_msgs_depends valid_packages = valid_packages + rospack.get_depends(package_context, implicit=True) TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "set") to list Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 873, in <module> generate_srv(sys.argv[1]) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 822, in generate_srv write_srv_component(s, spec.request, spec) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 697, in write_srv_component write_md5sum(s, spec, parent) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 596, in write_md5sum compute_files=False) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 314, in get_dependencies _add_msgs_depends(rospack, spec.response, deps, package) File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/gentools.py", line 75, in _add_msgs_depends valid_packages = valid_packages + rospack.get_depends(package_context, implicit=True) TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "set") to list make[3]: *** [../srv_gen/lisp/SetCompliancePunch.lisp] Error 1 make[3]: *** [../srv_gen/lisp/SetSpeed.lisp] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/joe/fuerte/sandbox/trunk/dynamixel_controllers/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_gensrv_lisp.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/joe/fuerte/sandbox/trunk/dynamixel_controllers/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/joe/fuerte/sandbox/trunk/dynamixel_controllers/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package dynamixel_controllers written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/joe/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130719-115348/dynamixel_controllers/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamixel_controllers [FAIL] [ 3.63 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package dynamixel_controllers.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 13 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/joe/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130719-115348
`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67782/trying-to-install-dynamixel_controllers-in-fuerte-getting-error/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that you are using Ubuntu 12.04, there should be packages available for dynamixel_motor stack on Fuerte. Any reason you are trying to compile from source?

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-07-22**:
When I did a search using the ROS search bar, that was the package that came up. I did not see the dynamixel_motor stack until after troubleshooting.
I have since found it but haven't confirmed that things are working properly yet. I will post back once I have made sure everything is working properly.